# Can I Git checkout 1 file while preserving merge conflicts?

Tags: git

## Problem

I have 3 branches, `main`, `dev`, and `feature`. Both `feature` and `dev` have modified file `myFile`. I am currently on the `feature` branch with a clean working tree, and I want to merge `dev` into `feature`. However, there are merge conflicts in `myFile`.

I want to combine the changes to `myFile` from `dev` and `feature` **and end up with conflict markers in the file**.

## Setup

Here are the steps to follow to set this situation up.

1. `mkdir test` create a repo
2. `cd test`
3. `git init`
4. `git checkout -b main` checkout the main branch
5. `touch myFile` check in a file
6. `git add myFile`
7. `git commit -m "add myFile"`
8. `git checkout -b dev` create a dev branch
9. `echo 'aaa' > myFile` modify the file
10. `git commit -am "change myFile"`
11. `touch fileB` do some other changes
12. `git add fileB`
13. `git commit -m "add fileB"`
14. `git checkout -b feature main` create a feature branch
15. `echo 'bbb' > myFile` modify the file differently
16. `git commit -am "change myFile"`
17. `touch fileC` do some other changes
18. `git add fileC`
19. `git commit -m "add fileC"`

Now everything is set up and your history looks like this:

[image: gitk]

It's time to pull the changes in from `dev` into `feature` for `myFile` only, leaving the rest of the file tree untouched.

1. `git merge dev` on no, conflicts!
2. `git status`

```
On branch feature
You have unmerged paths.
  (fix conflicts and run "git commit")
  (use "git merge --abort" to abort the merge)

Changes to be committed:
        new file:   fileB

Unmerged paths:
  (use "git add <file>..." to mark resolution)
        both modified:   myFile
```

The goal is to change the contents of `myFile` to

```
<<<<<<< HEAD
bbb
=======
aaa
>>>>>>> dev
```

without modifying any other files at all.

How do you do that? Look at the "working but not nice solutions" below to see some methods for how to achieve this. But the point of this question is to discover if there is an easier or simpler way to do it, because I don't think the ways I listed below are very simple.

## Failed Solutions

### ❌ `git checkout dev -- myFile`

This just gives me the exact file that is in the `dev` branch, removing any changes that have been made on the `feature` branch.

### ❌`git diff` + `git apply` ([reference](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22689198/4476484))

1. `git diff feature dev -- myFile > temp.patch`.
2. `git apply temp.patch`.
3. `rm temp.patch`

This also ends up with a file that has no conflict markers in it.

*Bonus note: if the order is wrong (i.e. `git diff dev feature -- myFile > temp.patch`) then it won't work at all.*

### ❌`git cherry-pick`

This is often recommended for this kind of fix, but there's no commit to cherry pick here. I need a file, not a commit. There could be dozens or hundreds of commits that touched `myFile`.

## Working but not nice solutions

### New branch + copy file + merge

1. `git checkout main`
2. `git branch deleteme`
3. `git checkout deleteme`
4. `git checkout dev -- myFile`
5. `git commit -m "grab myFile from dev"`
6. `git checkout feature`
7. `git merge deleteme`

(Then later on remember to `git branch -D deleteme`)

This is kind of terrible and muddies up the history. Plus you have to create a temporary branch.

### 3-way merge with common ancestor

1. `git show dev:myFile > dev-version`
2. `git show main:myFile > main-version`
3. `git merge-file myFile main-version dev-version`
4. `rm dev-version main-version`

This is slightly shorter than the above method, but requires temporary files.

### Merge the branches and then reset or revert everything else

I don't even want to think about doing this.

## Question

Is there any way to do this that doesn't involve creating temporary files/branches?

[Potential duplicate question with no answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63322518/4476484)

Comment: Your second working solution seems like exactly answering what you want to do. You could put it in a script which also deletes the temporary files if that makes you feel better

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're asking for, nor what its purpose is. Do you want to merge dev and feature, but only myFile? Do you plan to commit it? Do you want only look at the conflicts for one file?

Comment: I think that duplicate answers your question. If it doesn't, leave a comment about how your question is different and I'll reopen.

Comment: That question is very similar, yes, but the answers there don't work for this question. The top answer there requires an interactive patch, which doesn't accomplish my goal of leaving the conflict markers in place. The next few answers describe other methods already  discussed here. But in any event, I think I'm satisfied with the answer of "there isn't really a better way to do this; sorry."

Comment: @nullromo It remains unclear to me what you're asking for. Could you give a concrete example? `git init` a repository, show us the commands to get into your situation, and then show us the result you'd like. Also, please explain the purpose, that might help us understand.

Comment: I went ahead and added the reproduction steps, but I'm fine with this question being closed. Thanks for being diligent.

Comment: I see, the answers do work. I doubt you'll find much simpler than `git merge --no-commit <branch>; git restore --staged`. You can put that into a script. It's not magical, it's just making use of the staging area. Good luck.

Comment: Is this something you need often? Feels like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: No, I don't need this often. Yes, it is indeed an XY problem, that's correct. I already merged my branches a week ago. I just wanted to figure out a weird special niche thing (solution Y) that I couldn't figure out on my own, so I came to stack overflow to see if anyone could give a suggestion on how to do it.

The actual original problem (problem X) that brought me here was solved all along.

Answer (score 0):

## Point 1

Since you are only bringing in changes for a single file you very likely do NOT want to create a merge commit for this. A merge commit in git means that **ABSOLUTELY EVERYTHING** from the source branch is now considered resolved and adapted into the destination branch. Once you have created a merge commit you cannot merge the history from before that again later on.

## Point 2

> Plus you have to create a temporary branch.

> Is there any way to do this that doesn't involve creating temporary files/branches?

No. *If you're **not** constantly creating temporary branches all the time you are doing git wrong!*

Creating temporary branches or [temporary commits](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75010635/23118) are not only normal but essential in using git.

## Point 3

> there are merge conflicts in myFile. ... end up with conflict markers in the file.

The default conflict markers injected by git is a very poor solution in helping resolving the conflict, I agree. Luckily there are proper 3-way merge tools you can use instead like for instance [KDiff3](https://github.com/hlovdal/git-resolve-conflict-using-kdiff3).

Proper graphical 3-way merge tool one of these tools that after having started using it to resolve merge conflicts you never want to go back to not using one.

## Point 4

You probably want to do something like the following:

```bash
git checkout -b myfile_updates_from_dev feature
git merge dev

# Undo any automatic resolvement of non-myFile files. The following command automates this,
# if there is just a few files you can alternatively just run `git status` and then
# `git reset file1 file2 file3`.
git status --porcelain=1 | grep ^M | cut -c4- | tr '\012' '\000' | xargs -0 --no-run-if-empty git restore --staged

# Resolve conflicts with a nice graphical 3-way merge tool.
git-resolve-conflict-using-kdiff3
git commit -m "---temporary commit not used directly---"

git checkout feature
# Bringing in the changes from dev but without having it be a merge commit.
git diff feature myfile_updates_from_dev | git apply -
git add myFile
git commit -m "Bring in changes to myFile from dev branch" -m "Corresponding to commit 1234568 (some commit message)."

git branch -D myfile_updates_from_dev
```

## Point 5

The following

```bash
git checkout main
git branch deleteme
git checkout deleteme
```

can be simplified to just

```bash
git checkout -b deleteme main
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed comments! P1 Yes, exactly. P2 Ok. P3 But I actually _do_ want the conflict markers. I want the same behavior for `myFile` that would happen if I did a merge while conflicts are present (markers injected), but I don't want all the other files to also get changed and I don't want everything to be considered merged. P4 This method does the correct thing, but it's basically the same as my new branch method. P5 Cool! I didn't know about the additional `<start-point>` argument. Anyway, thanks.

Comment: Regarding point 3, the conflict marker are not missing here, they are still present and added to the file by git as normal, it is just that the 3-way merge tool ignores those and instead uses the "raw" contributing versions as inputs for its conflict resolution.

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear what you're asking for and why, but I think you want to see the merge conflicts for a single file.

Perform the merge, but don't commit it.

```
git merge --no-commit somebranch
```

Now you can `git diff myFile` and look at the conflicts (if any). The rest of the merge will be staged, but not committed.

When you're done you can return to the pre-merge state with `git merge --abort` if there were conflicts and `git restore --staged --worktree` if there were not.

Comment: Do not both close and answer.

Comment: @matt Excuse me, I found the duplicate after my answer. SO likes to close instantly because of my gold Git tag; I wish it gave me a choice.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but in this case `git merge --no-commit dev` is the exact same thing as `git merge dev` since there are conflicts. So this answer doesn't really add anything.

Comment: @nullromo It remains unclear to me what you're asking for, and for what purpose. "*I want to combine the changes to myFile from dev and feature and end up with conflict markers in the file.*" The answer does that, could you explain what is missing? You say "* Merge the branches and then reset or revert everything else. I don't even want to think about doing this.*" Could you explain what is unacceptable to you about that?

Comment: I clarified the question. However, please don't spend more of your time on this. The question can remain closed and we can move on. Thanks for the help and comments.